# Что если boot с x64 живой флешки Ubuntu на компе с x86

Tags: windows-8, live-usb

Что будет, не испортится ли оборудование? У моего друга ноутбук x64 c Windows 8 У меня x86 (32 бита) PC с Windows 7, нам нужно использовать Ubuntu, я в Win 7 через Universal USB Installer создал загрузочную живую флешку с Ubuntu x64 и местом для хранения параметров (на флешке). Теперь боюсь запускать на BOOT, что будет если запущю с моего x86 компа. У меня еще ценная очень инфа на HDD (NTFS 3 локальных диска) Из-за сбоя может  ли Ubuntu ее повредить если я не буду писать/чтать на HDD?

Comment: Запустил на 32 бит компе на 64 еще не проверял. Могу передавать/получать инфу и без этого но все таки не опасно ли нажать mount&open на локальном диске (NTFS от Windows) в Nautilus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тестили, тестили - нормально все. просто будьте сами поаккуратнее.

Comment: А если на локальном диске E: какая то запоратая файловая система (chkdsk и Acronis запорол) и там есть папка в которой ... та же папка в ней она же и т.д - циключеская папка:) И там есть unnalocated space и indexes которые chkdsk unable to recover?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не опасно, я уж так несколько лет копирую файлы туда-сюда.

Comment: Windows 7/8 вы тестили с ним? а то такая ненадежна ОСЬ Ubuntu я боюсь инфа важная Например я в Acronis Disk Director 2008 года форматировал C: как NTFS и потом установил Win 7 (это был ноут Toshiba) и ... read disk error! А когда через установщик Windows форматнул - то нормально.